Create declaration file for third party library as CJS
I am using a third party CommonJS (CJS) library without types. My project is CJS with TypeScript. The importation works just fine (imports are transpiled to requires) if I disable errors using comments.
/* c8 ignore start */
// @ts-ignore
import * as func from "third-party-library";

const example = func();

I wanted to get rid of these comments and get some more accurate typing, so I created a .d.ts file for the library. It appears to be accurate thanks to this answer and my IDE / eslint no longer complains about unknown types or the use of any;
// third-party-library.d.ts
declare module "third-party-library" {
  function func(): string;
  export = func;
}

All good so far, except now I get the following error;

This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.ts(2497)

I have read that the 'fix' for this is to add the esModuleInterop flag in my tsconfig.json as described.
However, I don't think this is the real fix because I am importing a CJS module into my pure CJS project. No modules or libraries are ESModules (ESM) I shouldn't need to do this.
As such, I believe that perhaps the declare in the library .d.ts is not quite accurate and the notation I am using is for ESM modules? Or perhaps I am importing incorrectly.
How can I resolve this without using esModuleInterop.

If you please, try when use of abbreviations such as "CJS" please try to add at least an initial non-abbreviation clarification of those. Example "Clearly Join Shelly (CJS)" with whatever it means to enhance clarity of your question. (I probably made the "wrong guess" here on purpose to illustrate where misconceptions might arise)

The answer was in this (ambiguously named) question.
// third-party-library.d.ts
declare module "third-party-library" {
  function func(): string;
  namespace func { }
  export = func;
}

